# Is asus X550LD--xx064d supports dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, ubuntu-drivers

I am trying to dual boot windows and ubuntu. but while installing ubuntu it can't detect other os windows7/8. also not detecting Hard Disk partitions.
Steps I followed:
1. Install windows 8.1 and then try to install ubuntu 14.04(No OS detected)
2. Install Windows 7 and then try to install ubuntu 14.04(No OS detected)

I] Please let me know is any problem due to windows 8 installation(Means need to change   bios setting, I have already tried security bios disable but unsuccessful).

II] Is this problem will fix by updating bios?
III] Also Ubuntu not detecting Hardwares like Touchpad/mouse, Nvidia graphics card not supporting functional keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What is the problem?

Windows 8 installs itself in UEFI mode, and it configures your BIOS to automatically run in UEFI mode. If you install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, you will have to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode and you will have to disable Windows 8 fast boot. This has worked perfectly on all laptops I have installed.

This guide tells you how to turn of fastboot and also secureboot. Ubuntu should be able to handle secureboot, but it won't hurt to also turn it off: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

After you install Ubuntu, you might have to run boot-repair. The guide also tells you how to do that.

## Will updating my BIOS help?

Yes, It might help. Newer versions of UEFI are more flexible and support Linux better.

Comment: I have tried process provided on http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html 1. I am not getting UEFI boot settings option, so i have disable "secure boot" from boot loader. while turn off fast boot as per provided information. 2. But when installing ubuntu 14.04 I am not getting list of partitions on "Installation Type" window and it shows whole hard disk.